# CPack adds system directories to generated RPM

Tags: cmake, rpm, yum, cpack

I have a CMake project and I use CPack to generate RPMs for my CentOS YUM repository. However, when I attempt to install my generated RPM, I get this error:

```
file /usr from install of clstrd-0.1.0-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
file /usr/bin from install of clstrd-0.1.0-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
file /usr/lib from install of clstrd-0.1.0-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
```

Further inspecting the RPM's contents, I see that it includes these files and directories:

```
$ rpm -qlp clstrd-0.1.0-Linux.rpm
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/clstrd
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libclstrd.a
```

**My question is:** How do I force CMake to exclude common directories like `/usr` or `/usr/bin` from the RPM? Shouldn't this be done automatically?

I have tried `CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION` with no luck.

**Edit:** Here are the relevant parts of my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# Targets
add_library(clstrd_lib ${SOURCE_FILES})
...
add_executable(clstrd main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(clstrd clstrd_lib)
...
# Installation configuration.
install(TARGETS clstrd_lib clstrd
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

# CPack configuration.
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "MyAwesomePackage")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "MyAwesomeVendor")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LICENSE.md")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "CMake ${CMake_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CMake_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "clstrd", "MyAwesomeExecutable")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_AUTOREQPROV " no")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_REQUIRES, "libpqxx, gtest, gflags, root,     root-netx, xrootd-client-libs")
set(CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION, "/usr /usr/bin /usr/lib")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "RPM")
include(CPack)
```

Comment: Did you also use `CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST` ? Can you post your usage of `CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION ` , perhaps you used it wrongly

Comment: take a look here: https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13609

Comment: @nos Nope, I edited the post so that you can see my explicit usage.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Thanks, you are correct. The best kind of correct. I was using v2.8.11 (latest v2 on EPEL) and this bug was fixed in the upcoming version. Fixed by transitioning to CMake3 and CPack3.

Comment: @PetrMánek; you're welcome. I added this as an answer so people can see the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this was a bug in cmake 2.8.9, which was fixed in cmake 2.8.12:

https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13609

Answer (score 4):

You can try this,

```
list(APPEND CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION "/lib")
list(APPEND CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION "/lib/systemd")
list(APPEND CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION "/lib/systemd/system")
```

Test OK on CentOS7 with cmake 2.8.12.2.